# Macbook pro with windows 10 audio driver install

Tags: bootcamp, audio, windows

Have installed windows 10 from ISO on macbook pro, but can't get audio drivers to work from boot camp - no MacOS installed.
Downloaded following bootcamp versions and extracted audio drivers without success.
Device manager shows "High def audio controller" - device cannot start.
Everything else is fine.

Mac:
Macbook pro core i5 13" Mid-2012

Bootcamps tried:

5.1.5621

5.1.5722

5.1.5769 (latest)

Am new to Macs so any advice welcome TQ

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem, I fixed it using the drivers from boot camp 4.xxxx.